# Count group by joining tables

Tags: join, count, group-by

I'm doing a query to show a count of members' uploads to my site.

So far I've got the basic count:

```
SELECT member_id,COUNT(*)  
FROM uploads        
GROUP BY member_id
```

...which, when echoed, displays the member_id and the amount of uploads they have.

However, what I'd like to do is display the member's firstname and lastname instead of just their id.

To do this I need to join the members and uploads table where members.member_id = uploads.member_id

I know I need to select **members.member_firstname**, **members.member_lastname**, **members.member_id** and **uploads.member_id**  where members.member_id = uploads.member_id and throw in the count and group by. I'm just stumped by the syntax. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT members.member_firstname, members.member_lastname, COUNT(*)  
FROM uploads    
JOIN members
ON uploads.member_id = members.member_id
GROUP BY uploads.member_id
```

Try that.

Comment: Thanks Amo,  I tried  your solution which was almost perfect. The only thing needed was to alter your last line from "GROUP BY member_id" to "GROUP BY uploads.member_id". Thank you again!!!!